# XorStr not compiling in x86

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

My code and the api im using relies hevily on XorStr and i need to be X86, But when i complie in x86 a error pops up on line 57 "negative integral constant converted to unsigned type", No red underlining. But when i complie in x64 it complies and works as intened. Heres a snipit of Xorstr.

```
template<typename _string_type, size_t _length>
class _Basic_XorStr
{
    using value_type = typename _string_type::value_type;
    static constexpr auto _length_minus_one = _length - 1;
public:
    constexpr ALWAYS_INLINE _Basic_XorStr(value_type const (&str)[_length])
        : _Basic_XorStr(str, std::make_index_sequence<_length_minus_one>())
    {
    }
    inline auto c_str() const
    {
        decrypt();
        return data;
    }
    inline auto str() const
    {
        decrypt();
        return _string_type(data, data + _length_minus_one);
    }
    inline operator _string_type() const
    {
        return str();
    }
private:
    template<size_t... indices>
    constexpr ALWAYS_INLINE _Basic_XorStr(value_type const (&str)[_length], std::index_sequence<indices...>)
        : data{ crypt(str[indices], indices)..., '\0' },
        encrypted(true)
    {
    }
    static constexpr auto XOR_KEY = static_cast<value_type>(
        const_atoi(__TIME__[7]) +
        const_atoi(__TIME__[6]) * 10 +
        const_atoi(__TIME__[4]) * 60 +
        const_atoi(__TIME__[3]) * 600 +
        const_atoi(__TIME__[1]) * 3600 +
        const_atoi(__TIME__[0]) * 36000
        );
    static ALWAYS_INLINE constexpr auto crypt(value_type c, size_t i)
    {
        return static_cast<value_type>(c ^ (XOR_KEY + i));
    }
    inline void decrypt() const
    {
        if (encrypted)
        {
            for (size_t t = 0; t < _length_minus_one; t++) //Error happens here, only in x86
            {
                data[t] = crypt(data[t], t);
            }
            encrypted = false;
        }
    }
    mutable value_type data[_length];
    mutable bool encrypted;
};
```

Thanks if you can help!
(Im using latest VS2019 with buildtools v142 and with 10.0.22000.0 Windows SDK, Sorry if anything i say sounds wrong, Still learning c++ at TAFE)

edit: i did some reserch and the github for XorStr said MSVC doesn't Like it anymore (https://github.com/KN4CK3R/XorStr). It maybe a Visual Studio error. If it is then can you guys suggest any good alternatives to XorStr.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Basic_XorStr`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Note that the `inline` in `inline auto c_str() const` isn't needed. Member functions defined inside a class definition are implicitly inline.

Comment: What do i change it to then? just Basic_XorStr or just XorStr?

Comment: This snipped does not race any error until a [mcve] with the template usage is shown.

Comment: `value_type data[_length]`  and `for (size_t t = 0; t < _length_minus_one; t++) data[t] = crypt(data[t], t);` with unused `data[_length - 1]` is suspicious.

Comment: Is the code you uploaded from the link you mentioned? Because I found that they have the same place. I tested the code in the link and it can run regardless of whether it is x86 or x64. You could refer to my installation details or reset visual studio settings. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs2qR.png

Comment: I got it to compile for x86 2 times everything worked fine, then after changing 1 line the error poped up and i cant compile anymore. The same error c4308

Comment: Did your change make the expression meaningless? As far as I know, [C4038](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4038?view=msvc-170) is caused by meaningless expression.

Comment: no i didn't, It complies sometimes. If i make new lines and del them it complies, sometimes it refuses to compile a couple of times and others it just complies. Its weird

Comment: If you make sure there is no problem with the code, I suggest you repair Visual Studio.